# How to install driver for DVB-T2 USB TUNER EVOLVEO SIGMA T2 on UBUNTU 17.10 (or newer ubuntu rls.)?

Tags: drivers, 17.10, 18.04, dvb, dvb-t

When i connect my EVOLVEO SIGMA T2

and type `lsusb` in terminal,

linux identifies new device as ID `ID 0572:c68a Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc.`

but w_scan command returns only error

```
w_scan version 20170107 (compiled for DVB API 5.10)
using settings for CZECH REPUBLIC
DVB aerial
DVB-T Europe
scan type TERRESTRIAL, channellist 4
output format vlc xspf playlist
output charset 'ISO-8859-1'
Info: using DVB adapter auto detection.
main:4007: FATAL: ***** NO USEABLE TERRESTRIAL CARD FOUND. *****
Please check wether dvb driver is loaded and
verify that no dvb application (i.e. vdr) is running.
```

How can I install driver for EVOLVEO SIGMA T2 and then successfuly scan for **dvb-t** & **dvb-t2** channels ?

Comment: so, ID 0572:c68a is equal to "Geniatech T230C2" ... evolveo is propably just local rebranding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device 0572:c68a is supposed to be covered by the driver *dvb-usb-cxusb*, however, the exact usb.id isn't included yet in the version included in the latest stable Ubuntu version, 17.10 and, therefore, earlier. Let's build a newer driver.

Please try this with a working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git build-essential
git clone https://bitbucket.org/CrazyCat/media_build.git
cd media_build
./build --git https://github.com/crazycat69/linux_media latest
sudo make install
```

It builds with a few possibly harmless warnings for me. The new driver reports:

```
$ modinfo dvb-usb-cxusb | grep C68
alias:          usb:v0572pC68Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0572pC689d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0572pC688d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

As you can see, your device is included. As a part of the install process, the needed firmware is also installed.

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. I will have a few more instructions.

**EDIT**: You have compiled the driver for your current kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the required reboot, recompile:

```
cd media_build
make distclean
git pull
./build
sudo make install
```

Comment: Amazing, after i finished descriebed procedure and rebooted my PC. `w_scan` succesfully found all DVB-T channels and then automaticaly found all DVB-T2 channels too ... it works as expected now :-) Thank you. Btw, here is my full `w_scan` output https://justpaste.it/1jhq3

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: ERROR 404 https://github.com/crazycat69/linux_media/ repository not found

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: @chili555 after typing `git clone https://bitbucket.org/CrazyCat/media_build.git
cd media_build`, the output is:

`Cloning into 'media_build'...`
`remote: You may not have access to this repository or it no longer exists in this workspace. If you think this repository exists and you have access, make sure you are authenticated.`
`fatal: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/CrazyCat/media_build.git/' not found`
`bash: cd: media_build: No such file or directory`

Comment: @luisito_36 A lot changes in 5+ years. Please start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 Already, https://askubuntu.com/q/1477979/849328