# How to install driver for DVB-T2 HDTV USB Stick - T230C on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, tv, dvb, dvb-t

After connecting that USB stick to my PC, I've checked typing `lsusb`. The output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0572:c68a Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc. EyeTV Stick
```

Then, I installed typing in terminal `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install w-scan`. Then typing `w_scan`, the output is the following:

```
w_scan 
w_scan version 20170107 (compiled for DVB API 5.11)
guessing country 'ES', use -c <country> to override
using settings for SPAIN
DVB aerial
DVB-T Europe
scan type TERRESTRIAL, channellist 4
output format vdr-2.0
output charset 'UTF-8', use -C <charset> to override
Info: using DVB adapter auto detection.
/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0 -> TERRESTRIAL "Silicon Labs Si2168": very good :-))

Using TERRESTRIAL frontend (adapter /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0)
-_-_-_-_ Getting frontend capabilities-_-_-_-_ 
Using DVB API 5.11
frontend 'Silicon Labs Si2168' supports
DVB-T2
INVERSION_AUTO
QAM_AUTO
TRANSMISSION_MODE_AUTO
GUARD_INTERVAL_AUTO
HIERARCHY_AUTO
FEC_AUTO
BANDWIDTH_AUTO not supported, trying 6/7/8 MHz.
FREQ (48.00MHz ... 870.00MHz)
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ 
Scanning DVB-T...
Scanning 8MHz frequencies...
474000: (time: 00:00.051) 
482000: (time: 00:02.059) 
490000: (time: 00:04.063) 
[ so on... ]
Scanning DVB-T2...
474000: (time: 01:38.302) 
482000: (time: 01:40.306) 
490000: (time: 01:42.310)
[ so on... ]

ERROR: Sorry - i couldn't get any working frequency/transponder
 Nothing to scan!!
```

Then, I tried the another way: I typed in terminal `sudo apt-get install dvb-apps` and I installed `Kaffeine` from **Ubuntu Software**.

After that, I opened Kaffeine, at the top of the window, I clicked `Television` and then `Configure Television`, at the tab `Device 1` I set up for the signal of my country. And finally, at the top of the window, clicked `Television` and `Channels`, and click the button `Start Scan`, the output is that it coudn't find any channel, so the list of channels is empty.

I think the driver for the device is missed. Does anyone advice me?

Answering to **@chili555** from the comment, I typed `lsmod | grep dvb`. The output is the following:

```
dvb_usb_dvbsky         24576  0
dvb_usb_v2             49152  1 dvb_usb_dvbsky
m88ds3103              40960  1 dvb_usb_dvbsky
dvb_core              155648  3 dvb_usb_v2,m88ds3103,dvb_usb_dvbsky
mc                     65536  3 si2157,dvb_usb_v2,dvb_core
rc_core                65536  5 dvb_usb_v2,rc_total_media_in_hand_02,cec,dvb_usb_dvbsky
```

And `sudo dmesg | grep -i dvb`, the output is the following:

```
[40312.264709] usb 1-5: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2' in warm state
[40312.265117] usb 1-5: dvb_usb_v2: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer
[40312.265141] dvbdev: DVB: registering new adapter (MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2)
[40312.265949] dvbdev: dvb_create_media_entity: media entity 'dvb-demux' registered.
[40312.281314] usb 1-5: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Silicon Labs Si2168)...
[40312.281318] dvbdev: dvb_create_media_entity: media entity 'Silicon Labs Si2168' registered.
[40312.281705] rc rc0: MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/rc/rc0
[40312.281771] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver dvb_usb_dvbsky registered at minor = 0, scancode receiver, no transmitter
[40312.281804] input: MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/rc/rc0/input35
[40312.281876] usb 1-5: dvb_usb_v2: schedule remote query interval to 300 msecs
[40312.281879] usb 1-5: dvb_usb_v2: 'MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2' successfully initialized and connected
[40507.244626] si2168 5-0064: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw failed with error -2
[40507.244642] si2168 5-0064: firmware file 'dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw' not found
[40507.272661] si2168 5-0064: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw failed with error -2
[40507.272677] si2168 5-0064: firmware file 'dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw' not found
[40533.546811] si2168 5-0064: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw failed with error -2
[40533.546815] si2168 5-0064: firmware file 'dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw' not found
```

According to that, the firmware is missed.

Following the steps of **@chili555**: After rebooting, I typed `sudo dmesg | grep -i dvb` and the output is the same as the previous output in above but without lines about firmware. Then, I typed `w_scan` and I got the same error in the output, later I typed again `sudo dmesg | grep -i dvb` and the output is a little different: "downloading firmware"...

```
[   11.840947] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2' in warm state
[   11.847400] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer
[   11.847427] dvbdev: DVB: registering new adapter (MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2)
[   11.847954] dvbdev: dvb_create_media_entity: media entity 'dvb-demux' registered.
[   11.915779] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Silicon Labs Si2168)...
[   11.915791] dvbdev: dvb_create_media_entity: media entity 'Silicon Labs Si2168' registered.
[   11.953180] rc rc0: MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0
[   11.953244] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver dvb_usb_dvbsky registered at minor = 0, scancode receiver, no transmitter
[   11.953295] input: MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0/input10
[   11.953343] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: schedule remote query interval to 300 msecs
[   11.953350] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 'MyGica Mini DVB-(T/T2/C) USB Stick T230C v2' successfully initialized and connected
[   11.953409] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_dvbsky
[  136.163771] si2168 6-0064: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw'
```

After that, I tried with Kaffeine and it couldn't get any channel yet.

Comment: This will not help you, but [Sundtek](https://shop.sundtek.de/) supports Linux and has an outstanding support. I'm running their hardware since over 10 years... [Check my app using it](https://github.com/kanehekili/MicroDVBRecorder)

Comment: "*I think the driver for the device is missed*" Were that true, there would be no communication with the hardware at all. Your output shows lots of communication. A bit more troubleshooting might pay off handsomely for you. Your two outputs don't match: `Connexant` vs. `Silicon Labs`. Do you have more than one TV stick plugged in?

Comment: The driver for your 0572:c68a device is *dvb_usb_dvbsky*. Did it load? `lsmod | grep dvb` Are there any interesting messages in the log? `sudo dmesg | grep -i dvb`

Comment: "guessing country 'ES'" Is this correct?

Comment: @chili555 Thank you, I just checked typing `w_scan -c CO`, I got the same error. And I've already checked about loading it, I just added the output in the question about it.

Comment: @user535733 I have only one TV stick plugged in.

Comment: Google for the firmware and add it to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your dmesg output suggests that you are missing required firmware. Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://github.com/CoreELEC/dvb-firmware/blob/5ed22312b7a0231a982e8c253dfca4d0d291c820/firmware/dvb-demod-si2168-d60-01.fw
```

Reboot and show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i dvb
```

Comment: Updated my question...

Comment: I see no errors or warnings in your dmesg. I regret that I have no other suggestions. Possibly helpful: https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/W_scan_cpp